# Unauthorized message when testing connection to bot from the bot framework developer portal

Tags: botframework

I have created a bot application and registered with the bot framework developer portal.

It works fine in the emulator without any issue but when performing the connection test from the bot framework developer portal I receive the Unauthorized message even I have filled in values correctly for the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword in the web.config.

It works when i have removed the BotAuthentication attribute tied to the Post method.

I am using the botframework v3 now ...

Anyone has encountered this error ? I have browsed through all the answers provided but none of it seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you been able to get it to work in the emulator (using local host for both the bot and emulator) with the AppId and AppPassword set?  If it doesn't work there it's an indication that your values are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have some problem with registered end point. Use https://yourendpointaddress/api/messages when registering in Bot directory and try the test connection. Hope this helps.